# Shading the entire $i$-th row and $j$-th column of an $m\times n$ grid when $\gcd(i,m)>1$ and $\gcd(j,n)>1$, how many grids leave $x$ cells unshaded?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Is there a way of cleverly counting the following scenario?

> Given an $m\times n$ grid, with $m$ and $n$ relatively prime, imagine shading a subset of the squares of an $m\times n$ grid using this procedure:
>
> - For each $i \in \{1,\dots,m\}$ such that $\gcd(i,m)>1$, shade all of the squares in the $i^\text{th}$ row.
> - For each $j\in \{1,\dots,n\}$ such that $\gcd(j,n)>1$, shade all of the squares in the $j^\text{th}$ column.
>
> Let $\sigma (x)$ be the number of ways to choose the ordered pair $(m,n)$ such $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime, and that there are exactly $x$ unshaded squares when you do this procedure.
>
> **Question**: Is there a clever way to compute $\sigma(x)$?

For example $\sigma (8)$ represents the number of $m\times n$ squares such that it has $8$ holes. I can think of two grids which are in $\sigma(8$) and those are $3\times 5$ grids and the $4\times 5$ grids as drawn below (I shaded the third row and $5$th row for the $3\times 5$ grid as $3$ and $5$ are the only prime factors of the row and column numbers of $3$ and $5$ greater than $1$):

[image]

But there might be more than these two grids which are in $\sigma (8)$, so is there a formula for counting the total number of grids which fall under $\sigma(x)$ for any $0\le x $?

Comment: For the $4 \times 5$ grid, shouldn't we only shade the $2$nd row and the $5$th column? Why is the $4$th row shaded, even though $4$ is not a prime number?

Comment: For the row number in $4\times 5$ grid its 4. So 4 has a prime factor of 2. So from the row number 1,2,3,4 the only ones which has a prime factor of 2 is 2,4 so I shaded 2 and 4. Let me correct the problem.

Comment: Note that the number of unshaded squares is exactly $\phi(m)\phi(n)$ where $\phi$ is the Euler Totient function, and in fact is equal to $\phi(mn)$ since $m,n$ are coprime. So the question is equivalent to finding numbers $t$ such that $\phi(t)=x$ and looking at decompositions of $t$ into two coprime factors.

Comment: Could you kindly give me an example of how to use the totient function for a specific value of $x$ ?

Comment: You should add restriction $m<n$.

Comment: @AuroraBorealis: What's the motivation for this problem? Please post more results from your personal investigation (eg, sample grids up to a certain size, any $\sigma(x)$ values you know (or a sense of why you *don't* know), tools and results you have used, etc, etc, etc). This will help readers wrap their minds around the puzzle, as well as help them avoid spending time duplicating your effort.

Comment: Assuming $n>m$, is it still considered a “grid” if $m=1$, or shall we suppose $m\ge2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think there is an explicit formula for this. However we can calculate it for a specific x. We find that the number of non shaded squares is $\phi(m) \phi(n)$. This is because $\phi(m)$ is the number of unshaded rows and $\phi(n)$ is the number of unshaded columns. We can simplify this to $\phi(mn)$ because they are relative prime. There is to my knowledge no explicit inverse function for $\phi$. In this link https://www.dcode.fr/euler-totient. It calculates it using an algoritm. (It also links how the algoritm works.) For example it gives for $x = 8$ the numbers $mn = 15,16,20,24,30$. We can find $\sigma(x)$ by finding al the different $m,n$ such that $m\times n = 15,16...30$ and counting these. (There are many ways to do this.) Thus for example is in this case $m = 4, n=4$ also a solution, because $4 \times 4 = 16$ and $\phi(16) = 8$. This is a long process, but I cannot make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comment of @Mor A., the number $x$ of unshaded squares for given co-prime $m$, $n$ is  $\phi(m)\phi(n)=\phi (mn)$. This product is always even. A brief table may help.

$$\begin{array}{c|clr} x & m\cdot n & \phi(m\cdot n) & \sigma(x) \\\hline 2 & 1\cdot3,1\cdot4,1\cdot6, 2\cdot3 & 1\cdot2 & 4\\4 & 1\cdot5,1\cdot8,1\cdot 10,1\cdot12,2\cdot5 & 1\cdot 4 & 5\\6 & 1\cdot7,1\cdot9,1\cdot14,1\cdot18,2\cdot7,2\cdot9 & 1\cdot6 & 6\\8 & 1\cdot15,1\cdot16,1\cdot20,1\cdot24,1\cdot30,2\cdot15;3\cdot5,3\cdot8,3\cdot10, 4\cdot5 & 1\cdot8;2\cdot4 & 10\\10 & 1\cdot11,1\cdot22, 2\cdot11 & 1\cdot10 & 3\\12 & 1\cdot13,1\cdot21,1\cdot26,1\cdot28,1\cdot36,1\cdot42, 2\cdot13,2\cdot21; 3\cdot7,3\cdot14,4\cdot7,4\cdot9,6\cdot7 & 1\cdot 12; 2\cdot 6 & 13\\14\\16 & 1\cdot17,1\cdot32,1\cdot34,1\cdot40,1\cdot48,1\cdot60, 2\cdot17;3\cdot16,3\cdot20 & 1\cdot16;2\cdot 8 & 9\\18 & 1\cdot19,1\cdot27,1\cdot38,1\cdot54, 2\cdot19,2\cdot27 & 1\cdot18 & 6\\20 & 1\cdot25,1\cdot33,1\cdot44,1\cdot66,2\cdot25,2\cdot33;3\cdot11,3\cdot22 & 1\cdot20;2\cdot 10 & 8\\  \end{array}$$To compute $\sigma (x)$ we must count all co-prime $(m,n)$ pairs for which $\phi(mn)=x$. This can be done, since for every (totient) even $x=ab$ there is a greatest integer $k$ such that $\phi(k)=ab$.

For example, in the array above, $x=1\cdot8=\phi(mn)$ only for$$mn=1\cdot15,1\cdot16,1\cdot20, 1\cdot24, 1\cdot30, 2\cdot15$$since $30$ is the greatest $n$ for which $\phi(n)=8$, and $2$ is the greatest $m$ for which $\phi(m)=1$.

Further, $x=2\cdot4=\phi(mn)$ only for$$mn=3\cdot5,3\cdot8,3\cdot10,4\cdot5$$since $10$ is the greatest $n$ for which $\phi(3)\phi(n)=2\cdot4$, and $3$ is the greatest odd $m$ for which $\phi(m)=2$.

Finally, $5$ is the greatest $n$ for which $\phi(4)\phi(n)=2\cdot4$. Thus for $x=8$,$$\sigma(x)=6+4+10$$[**Note**: There are no solutions for $x=14$ in the sample above, since ${14,26,34,38,50,62,…}$ ([OEIS A005277](https://OEIS.org/A005277)), a subsequence of even $x$, are **non-totients**, i.e. are not $\phi(x)$ for any $x$, and thus like odd $x$ can be set aside.]

For a second, somewhat lengthier example, let $x=60$. Possible $2$-factor $x=ab=60$ are$$1\cdot60,2\cdot30,3\cdot20,4\cdot15,5\cdot12,6\cdot10$$However we can discard all pairs with an odd factor $>1$ since, except for $\phi(1)$ and $\phi(2)=1$, $\phi(mn)$ is always even $\times$ even. Accordingly we have$$\begin{array}{c|cl} 60 & m\cdot n & \phi(m\cdot n)\\\hline 1\cdot 60 & 1\cdot61,1\cdot77,1\cdot93,1\cdot99,1\cdot122,1\cdot124,1\cdot154,1\cdot186,1\cdot198 & 1\cdot 60\\2\cdot30 & 3\cdot31,3\cdot62, 4\cdot31, 6\cdot31 & 2\cdot30\\6\cdot10 & 7\cdot11,7\cdot22,9\cdot11,9\cdot22,14\cdot11,18\cdot11 & 6\cdot10\end{array}$$Thus for $x=60$,$$\sigma(x)=9+4+6=19$$

Although not a formula, and potentially time-consuming, this is a reliable method for computing $\sigma(x)$, given access to the Euler totient sequence for sufficiently large $x$ ([OEIS A000010](https://OEIS.org/A000010)).